# How to insert a key-value pair after a specified key in a JSON object using jq?

Tags: json, insert, edit, key-value, jq

I have a JSON file like this

```
{
    "hierarchy": {
        "structure": {
            "card_11001": [
                "addCard_4111"
            ],
            "container_11006": [
                "mainContainer_11007",
                "subContainer_10016"
            ],
            "mainContainer_11007": [
                "paymentMethodList_10001"
            ],
            "orderWrap_10012": [
                "orderSummary_10005"
            ],
            "paymentMethodList_10001": [
                "card_11001",
                "placeOrder_10013"
            ],
            "root_10000": [
                "payNotice_11011",
                "payNotice_10020",
                "container_11006",
                "placeOrderResultAction_10004"
            ],
            "subContainer_10016": [
                "orderWrap_10012",
                "footer_10014"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to insert

```
"offline_11018": [
    "instruction_908",
    "checkboxList_11019"
]
```

Between `"mainContainer_11007"` and `"orderWrap_10012"` so the result I want should look like this:

```
{
    "hierarchy": {
        "structure": {
            "card_11001": [
                "addCard_4111"
            ],
            "container_11006": [
                "mainContainer_11007",
                "subContainer_10016"
            ],
            "mainContainer_11007": [
                "paymentMethodList_10001"
            ],
            "offline_11018": [
                "instruction_908",
                "checkboxList_11019"
            ],
            "orderWrap_10012": [
                "orderSummary_10005"
            ],
            "paymentMethodList_10001": [
                "card_11001",
                "placeOrder_10013"
            ],
            "root_10000": [
                "payNotice_11011",
                "payNotice_10020",
                "container_11006",
                "placeOrderResultAction_10004"
            ],
            "subContainer_10016": [
                "orderWrap_10012",
                "footer_10014"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

All I know is that I can only append it to the end of file with

```
jq --raw-output '.hierarchy.structure + {"offline_11018": ["instruction_908","checkboxList_11019"]}'
```

But that's not what I want, I want to insert it between two other keys. How can I do it with the jq command?

Comment: The keys in an objects are unordered. As long as the new key is added to the correct object, it doesn't matter where the key exists.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach would be to use `to_entries` to convert `.hierarchy.structure` into an array, perform the insertion, and then use `from_entries` to reconstitute the object, along the lines of:

```
.hierarchy.structure |= (to_entries
  | ... as $ix
  | .[:$ix] + ($x | to_entries) + .[$ix:]
  | from_entries)
```

The above sketch of course would need to be modified if it is possible that the item defining the insertion point cannot be found.

### `indexof/1`

Here's a useful "def" for finding the least index for which some condition holds:

```
# If the input is an array, emit the least index, $i, 
# for which `.[$i]|f` is truthy, otherwise emit null.
# Works similarly if the input is a JSON object.
def indexof(f):
  label $out
  | foreach .[] as $x (null; .+1;
      if ($x|f) then (.-1, break $out) else empty end) // null;
```

### Solution using `indexof`

Putting the above pieces together:

```
{"offline_11018": [ "instruction_908", "checkboxList_11019" ]} as $x
| .hierarchy.structure |= (to_entries
    | (1 + indexof( .value | index("mainContainer_11007") )) as $ix
    | .[:$ix] + ($x | to_entries) + .[$ix:]
    | from_entries)
```

Comment: I tried your solution but I got an error, please check this out https://jqplay.org/s/YWyksyMM7V

Comment: You pasted in the outline, not the complete solution!